# Arch Linux: Cannot start X

Tags: arch-linux, x11, xorg, radeon, amd-graphics

I installed Catalyst drivers from the AUR using `makepkg -sri`, and the installation went through successfully. However, now I can't start X at all.

On boot, X tries to start but instead gives me a blue screen saying that X failed to start. The log files say the following errors:

```
...
(WW) glamor0: Failed to get GLSL version
(EE) RADEON(0): Failed to initialize glamor.
(EE) RADEON(0): Acceleration initialization failed
...

/usr/lib/xorg-server/Xorg: symbol lookup error:
/usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/radeon_drv.so: undefined symbol: exaGetPixmapDriverPrivate
```

That's just about all the info I get. The `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` has a file `20-radeon.conf` and it looks like this:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Radeon"
    Driver "radeon"
    Option "ColorTiling" "on"
    Option "ColorTiling2D" "on"
    Option "TearFree" "on"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

The file 20-radeon.conf actually make X load the open source driver with the line `Driver "radeon"`. The proprietary driver (Catalyst) is called "fglrx". I doubt, that changing just this line would work. You probably should remove this file from this folder.

The Catalyst driver has configuration tool for setting up X called *aticonfig*. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AMD_Catalyst#Configuring_the_driver for instructions on how to use it. It will replace `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with a working configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to try fixing your drivers with mhwd-gpu read the different options in —-help. This will help you get your drivers sorted out.

Comment: Which package is `mhwd-gpu` provided by? I am not familiar with it.

Comment: It should come as default.  Ill quickly ask